# Is there any way to access react native image's bitmap directly?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bitmap

I am working on a project which needs a lot of image processing on the client side. I need to blur some parts of the image, add RGB noise and so on.

I've already tried WebView Canvas based solution (https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas) but this package looks abandoned, so I've changed a plan.

I would like to work with Bitmap directly. Any ideas about how I can get the bitmap of an Image in react native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to access the raw bitmap data of the React Native `<Image>` (aka. RCTImage) component.

The best way to achieve what you're looking to do is likely going to be to use the Native UI Components API for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) to implement a custom native image view that applies the effects you are looking for.

Alternatively, you could look at packages like [gl-react-native](https://github.com/gre/gl-react/tree/master/packages/gl-react-native) to impement your effects as GL shaders.